# Maxmimum weight for USPS service

Tags: usps

I am trying to integrate USPS shipping service. I got it works. But I got warning message if i exceed weight limit I got message like "`Warning - The package weight cannot exceed 70 pounds.`" , Here i want to set USPS maximum weight limit. `Are USPS provide service up to MAXIMUM 70 lbs?`  IS it possible to set max weight limit ?

Comment: Maybe USPS would be a better place to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling `usps maximum package weight` tells me that they indeed have [a hard limit of 70 pounds.](https://tools.usps.com/go/ScheduleAPickupAction!input.action)

> Remember, we won't accept an item that's over 70 lbs or 130". Mail pieces weighing more than 13 oz bearing only stamps as postage are not eligible for pickup.